# REGEXP_SUBSTR in Snowflake, regex that will extract the string after the period (which occurs between 0-2 times)

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-substr

I'm trying to use the [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr) method in Snowflake to extract a string after the period. I have the following possibilities:

- `ALTER TABLE DATABASE_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN ....`
- `ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN ....`
- `ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN ....`

With the following possibilities, I need to be able to extract TABLE_NAME. So far, I've tried this which is able to get the third possibility:

```
select regexp_substr(query_text, 'ALTER TABLE ([0-9A-Za-z\\-\\_]+) ADD COLUMN', 1,1, 'e', 1);
```

I'm not sure how I could capture all three possibilities in one regular expression. Would appreciate any pointers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regexp and split_part:

```
WITH cte(query_text) AS (
   SELECT 'ALTER TABLE DATABASE_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN ....' UNION
   SELECT 'ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN ....' UNION
   SELECT 'ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN ....'
)
select 
  regexp_substr(query_text, 'ALTER TABLE (.+) ADD COLUMN', 1,1, 'e', 1) as obj_name,
  split_part(obj_name, '.', -1) AS tab_name,
  split_part(obj_name, '.', -2) AS schema_name,
  split_part(obj_name, '.', -3) AS db_name
FROM cte;
```

Output:

| OBJ_NAME | TAB_NAME | SCHEMA_NAME | DB_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DATABASE_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME | TABLE_NAME | SCHEMA_NAME | DATABASE_NAME |
| SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME | TABLE_NAME | SCHEMA_NAME |  |
| TABLE_NAME | TABLE_NAME |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select regexp_substr(query_text, 'ALTER TABLE ([0-9A-Za-z\\-\\_.]+\.)?([0-9A-Za-z\\-\\_]+) ADD COLUMN', 1, 1, 'e', 2);
```

Will do what you described.

```sql
select regexp_substr(query_text, 'ALTER TABLE (["0-9A-Za-z\\-\\_.]+\.)?"?([0-9A-Za-z\\-\\_]+)"? ADD COLUMN', 1, 1, 'e', 2);
```

Will also extract table name if it is in quotes.